# Maximum Number of Folders Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, max, subdirectory

I'm building a site(asp.net) that needs save images for each product, so I'm not sure how implement it. I think i can do it saving all photos in the same folder but i do not like that i would prefer to create a new subfolder for each product and save the images in that subfolder but maybe in the future i have problems due to limitations with number of folders or subfolders.

Do you think that second option (creating subfolders) is better and secure?

Comment: I think you need to change your question a bit and asked for information and not about "what do you would have choose".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see in the following link the limits of windows file system

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb457112.aspx

taken from

https://serverfault.com/questions/18692/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-or-folders-that-can-be-stored-in-a-single

the limits of files and sub folders changed depending the kind of server/netapp.
you can read in the link above the limits for each one.

I would use subfolders but it is up to you, the important thing is that you need to know the limits and then decide.